# Bar code font error with crystal report on web server

Tags: asp.net, fonts, crystal-reports, webserver, barcode

I am using a bar code font to display bar code in my crystal report. It's working fine but in one condition

It needs restart of machine after installing bar code font. So it's working good because after installing bar code font I simply restart the machine and it start's work.

But when I uploaded my project on web server the same condition occurs. My service provider installed bar code font on server but, it requires restart of server to take effects which is not possible.

So what is the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a old post.

But i had a issue with using a windows 10 computer with the font not registering even after i restarted the computer.

I found that the issue is that the font didnt get installed into the `windows/fonts` folder.

I tried dragging it into the correct folder but it still installed in `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`
I found the a solution is to right click on the font and click install for all users. 
That was only way that it installed it in the right folder.

Found in [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/installed-fonts-not-showing-up-in-windows-fonts/5fa9c4a1-e86c-4bd6-af33-13e249b3ec43?page=4)

I know that this is a different issue i just wanted to have the information available for anyone else that comes up with a similar issue.

Comment: I did not downvote but I believe there is a general dislike of answers where you have to drill down to the link to get the fix. I think that is you give more details from the linked site in your reply and just reference the link as a source you might not get the downvote. This is just my suspicion... I'm still learning the culture of this site myself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I did say what I found as a solution I guess it wasn't so clear. Ill edit it

Comment: For me the "Install for all users worked". Im on a win2019 server.

Comment: Year is 2021, and still this answer is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although many applications can detect the fonts installed using `Drag-n-Drop` or `Copy-Paste` to the `Windows\Fonts` folder, but *Crystal Reports needs the fonts to be registered*.

*Drag-n-Drop or a copy-paste of font in the Windows\Fonts will not be registered until the system is restarted*.

You'll have to ask your service provider to delete the copy/pasted or drag/dropped file from the Windows\Fonts folder and then **do a proper install of the font**, it will register it without restarting the system.

*Typically a font can be installed/registered in the system as follows*:

`Control Panel` > `Fonts` > `File Menu` > `Install New Font` > `Select Drive` of new font file > `Select Folder` of new font file > `Select New Font File` > `Select Copy Fonts To Fonts Folder CheckBox` > `OK`

Some options may vary depending on Windows version but procedure will be same. After installing/registering the font just close and re-open your Crystal Reports without restarting the system.

For official Microsoft reference of installing and removing fonts in common windows versions you may see [How to install or remove a font in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314960)

Comment: Hi @harman, Thanks for your kind interest. I requested my provider to install the font  same as you suggested and they installed it in same way. But problem remain the same. :(

Comment: Earlier, I had resolved such issue on my Windows Server 2008 using these steps. After your comment, just to confirm, I created a sample project and tested on my another server Windows Server 2012 and everything works fine (CR version 13.0.3, generic .ttf open licence (free) font). Not sure, but font type (.ttf, .otf, .fon, .ttc, .pfb etc.), license type (screen only, print only etc.) may have some implications.

Comment: Had you requested your service provider to install font on web server ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi Both servers are dedicated. Although I have full control over them, even to restart, but I did that during peak load hours without a restart

Comment: My server is not dedicated, it's shared hosting server. I can't control it. May be this is the main reason.

Comment: Some of my clients too have their own shared hosting and whenever there are some issues or situations like this I usually have to put much more effort to resolve these. Most of the time customer care personnel do not know technical details and they are hard to convince of the requirement. Anyways, other than restarting, the only solution left to your problem is the way mentioned above. You can test it on any other system.