# Crystal Report to Adobe PDF font issue

Tags: pdf, fonts, crystal-reports

I've searched in vain, off and on for several months, and still haven't found anyone else with this issue. Resolutions to similar issues aren't working for me or simply don't apply.

I have a web application written in Visual Studio.Net 2012 (C#/ASP.Net). The application pulls a small set of data from an Oracle table, and then uses Crystal Reports to throw that data onto a report page that is displayed by Adobe Acrobat within the browser. The Users then print out the individual Adobe Acrobat page as a 'coupon', and physically scans it into our document scanning system. This document scanning system DEMANDS a particular font, and here's the issue...Currently, the app is running in our production environment, and our User Acceptance Testing (UATest) environment. The Adobe Acrobat page is displaying a different font set for each web environment. On UATest, everything is displaying as it should. The font is OCR A Extended. It's a monospaced font that resembles the old Courier style.  On our production system, it's displaying what looks like Arial? Microsoft Sans Serif? I have no idea, but whatever it is, our scanning system doesn't like it and won't accept it.

The situation is what it is. I can't alter the river flow at this point. That means I'm stuck with the current methodology. Automating the process so that the data goes from website into the data tables on the scanner would be ideal, but that's not possible.

- The two web servers are both Windows Server 2012/R2.
- The IIS setup is identical for both applications on both web servers.
- I've synchronized all of the fonts and font settings on both web servers. They are exactly the same number and files for fonts on both machines.
- The application is internal to our department, and access to it is controlled through Active Directory. Not sure if that matters for this, but better to have too much info than not enough.
- The applications are identical, meaning that I've copied the entire application folder from the UATest machine where it displays the proper font, onto the Production machine where it doesn't.
- The font is set correctly and shows correctly in the Crystal Report creator on the development machine (my local machine used to code, compile, and deploy the app).
- The results are the same regardless of the browser used.
- I've gone into the Crystal Report, Right Clicked -> Design -> Default Settings -> Fonts Tab. And then set the default fonts to OCR A Extended for each possible object.

At this point, I've got my Users running the app from the UATest server. Not the most ideal solution, but it will have to hold until I find the fix for this.

Comment: I know this is a old post. But i just had the same issue it didn't help when i restarted the computer. I answered it in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857621/10852981 I just wanted it to be available if someone else comes across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. The fonts didn't/wont take effect on the web server until a restart is performed. Did one last night and the new Font is showing up like it should.